# Update Nifi CSD jar files

Tags: linux, installation, jar, apache-nifi, cloudera

I need help on Nifi Installation

I have nifi csd jar files in opt/cloudera/csd folder

owner and group is cloudera-scm

Now I have a requirement of deleting this existing csd jar files and putting new version of nifi csd jar files in the same folder opt/cloudera/csd folder

I have tried delete commands but I am not able to delete this existing nifi csd jar files.

Please help if you have come across same scenario

Tried linux delete commands

Comment: This sounds off-topic for SO. Please read [this Help Center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to learn what's on-topic here.

Comment: I am asking about nifi csd jar file deletion